# Tracing actions in a browser

Tags: debugging, browser

I need to code a script/macro that will interact with my sites for a CS course. Is there a way to use your browser to watch AJAX submissions so that you can record and then mimic them?

Comment: Which browser do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for chrome : (sorry i don't use firefox, i don't know this browser very well)

It exists a useful plugin to test your web api and send ajax call : 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm

Otherwise, you can use the default debugger of chrome, for this click on "Ctrl + Shift + i", there is 2 useful panels: 'Network' and 'Source'. (see the link below for more informations)

documentation : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging